# SQLlite comma escape in match query

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite, match, sql-like

I have a `match` query for example:

```
select * from items where itemdesc MATCH (',')
```

The data that it returns its complete non sense - something that contains semicolons, dots etc.

The `like` query returns a correct dataset however.

```
select * from items where itemdesc like ('%,%')
```

How do correctly return the data in the `MATCH` query when I have the comma - the same issue persists with apostrophes, not sure if there are more characters that the match query does not like.

Comment: Is `items` a standard or a Full Text Search table ?

Comment: its a virtual table after researching a bit I found that MATCH query does not like non alpha numeric chars... So i have started replacing non alpha numeric chars with spaces..... Works but would prefer it working properly....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQlite fts4 virtual tables don't handle punctuations and they just get replaced with the space instead...

https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#tokenizer

so what i did was just declare the tokenchars:

```
"tokenize=unicode61" +  " \"" +"tokenchars=.,/?!:;\\"
```

Your actual search string you have to wrap with quotes as well - `MATCH '",*"'`

it doesn't handle quotes though....